Browser Back Button using window.history.go and Javascript loads every page in history before getting to the final page
In my shopping cart page when visitors click "Update" or "Delete" the shopping cart page refreshes every time so naturally if a visitor clicks the browser's "Back" button they will get to the previous shopping cart page before their "Update" or "Delete".
So to get to the page before entering the shopping cart page when clicking the browser "Back" button I finally got it working with (all my pages use JavaScript and JQuery):
var myback = -1

$(".myordersubmitbutton").click(function() {   
    myback = myback - 1; 
});

if(performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
    window.history.go(myback);
}

And I know performance.navigation.type is being deprecated but it works on Chrome/Edge(Desktop) for now.
So the above code works perfectly it brings the visitor back to before they entered the shopping cart.
But both browsers (Chrome/Edge) reload all pages before getting to the "before entering cart", so if the above code runs window.history(-4) it loads page -1, then -2, then -3 before it finally gets to -4
My question: Shouldn't (as I read) a window.history(-4) jump straight back to that page from the browser history instead of reloading all the pages in between first? Thanks

If you want to avoid this kind of stuff, use location.replace(nextUrl) to replace the history entry. That means that if you are on page1 and do location.replace(page2) then when they hit the back button they are on page1, on page 2 when you do location.replace(page3) then when they hit the back button they are on page2

My guess would be, that myback doesn't actually contain, what you think it should/would. So you are going back with the default value -1, then that previous page loads. And because it was loaded by navigating the history, performance.navigation.type == 2 will again be true on that page, upon which you go back one more page, etc.

And FYI, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation : "Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes."

@CBroe Yes, just did another test and you could be correct

@CBroe You are a legend.....it was exactly as you said....because refreshing the page gave the myback always -1  .....fixed. Thank you very much

Please either:  1) close your question as no longer required (but thanks for the feedback) or 2) add an answer so others can benefit if they have a similar issue in the future.

Thanks and sorry. As I also answered my last question I thought it wasn't appropriate to take credit when it was really @CBroe's comment which made me fix it. I will answer now

If @CBroe want's to make a full answer then that's up to them - you can always change the accepted answer at a later date.  Having an answer (or close) just means people don't come to your question, read all the way through, then find it's already been resolved in the comments.   (should check comments first, but we don't always)

@fdomn-m Thank you again for all your info

So because on every "Update" or "Delete" the page refreshes the myback will always be:
var myback = -1

Not good with Java I added(as "Update"/"Delete" is a form) to those forms:
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$myback\" name=\"myback\">";

And at the top of the php page:
$myback = $_REQUEST["myback"];

If($myback == "")
{
$myback = -1;
}
else
{
$myback = $myback -1;
}

And my Java is now:
$(document).ready(function () {

if(performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
window.history.go(<?php echo $myback;?>);
}

});

Now it still refreshes 1 time as per normal Browser Back button but then it does the jump to lets say window.history(-4) and I can live with that

FYI [tag:Java] is not [tag:Javascript]

Hi @fdomn-m thank you(just saw your comment now). Appreciate all your help

Browser update, so as in my question performance.navigation.type == 2 works currently on Chrome/Edge(Desktop) but I just tested more browsers and it works on FF(Desktop & Mobile) but it doesn't work on Chrome Mobile.
